# HIVE LLAP doesn't work with complex types

Tags: hadoop, hive, ambari

I turned on LLAP on the Ambari sandbox and my queries aren't working anymore.

I have a table that has primitive types and complextypes(structs/arrays).

I'm querying against the primitive type and it errors out.

select * from test.data
where policynumber = '4'

Error:  java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask

Comment: LLAP has a number of limitations, cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771050/hive-llap-doesnt-work-with-parquet-format for instance. For starters, did you inspect the YARN logs for your query??

Comment: I'm quite the noob still.  I'll try to look at the yarn logs and see if it'll give any details.  I'm aware it has limitations, but I thought having the where clause on a primitive type would have helped.

Comment: My main issue right now is how slow it is finding a unique record on a primitive type column search, which is why I tried with llap.  Before llap, Aggregation is great, but searching by some unique key is horribly slow.  Tez, orc, primitive sorted columns for predicate, also has complex type columns well.  9 million records.  With llap, searching won't work at all

Comment: Looks like you are coming from another planet, and have never read anything about the Hadoop ecosystem... Hive was designed for MASSIVE, FULL-SCAN QUERIES on huge, immutable data files. Columnar file formats like ORC and Parquet allow "skip scan" (instead of full scan). CarbonData file format promises an "inverted index" but it's still experimental and has not been integrated to Hive yet. On the other hand, you can use HBase for key/value access. And you can use SolR or ElasticSearch for full text search. But these are different tools, for different purposes, and with different designs.

Comment: Bottom line : if you want to run OLTP queries on indexed tables, simply use MySQL on your laptop. Or even a small-footprint database like H2 or SQLite. Today, 9 million records score as "small data", it would probably run on your smartphone...

Comment: The reason I chose hadoop was primarily because the data coming in was large blobs of XML with a ton of nested objects that I didn't want to build out into tables.

Comment: Can you help me understand why ORC is slow then, without llap, and not usable with llap when the other columns are blobs but the "where" condition is on a primitive type?  I'm trying to set up this system for others to use SQL against.

Comment: And yep, I'm a real noob.  I'm a.net developer trying to make it so that all this XML which was so slow to query is fast to query.